# Index of unmatched string in a list of character vectors

Tags: r

I have a list of character vectors and I want to use grep command to find locations of what is not matched. See example below:

```
x.lst <- list()
x.lst[[1]] <- c("she", "said", "hello")
x.lst[[2]] <- c("hello")
x.lst[[3]] <- c("whats", "up")
```

I want a function to return index of unmatched pattern in each vector. In my example, return index of everything except "hello".  If I use following :

```
lapply(x.lst, function(x) x[-grep("hello",x)])
```

I get:

```
[[1]]
[1] "she"  "said"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)
```

the desired output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1    2

[[2]]
[1] character(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1    2
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `invert = TRUE` to return the index of the elements which do not match.

```
lapply(x.lst, function(x) grep("hello",x, invert = TRUE))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#integer(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2
```

---

A `tidyverse` alternative

```
library(tidyverse)
map(x.lst, ~ setdiff(seq_along(.), str_which(., "hello")))
#You can always do same as base here as well
#map(x.lst, ~ grep("hello",., invert = TRUE))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#integer(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed... Thanks Ronak!

Answer (score 1):

One option with `Map` from `base R`

```
unname(Map(grep, pattern = "hello", x.lst, invert = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(x.lst, ~ str_detect(.x, "hello") %>% 
               `!` %>% 
                which)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#integer(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  both solutions work but looks like tidyverse downloads a whole lot of stuff so i liked the combination of unname and MAP functions.

Comment: @seakyourpeak  I personally dont' download all the packages.  I would use only the relevant packages i.e. `stringr` (str_detect) and `purrr` (map) and `dplyr`

Comment: You mean if I were to only download purr I would have been fine as I already had stringr and dplyr

Comment: Yes, and load `library(purrr); library(dplyr);library(stringr)` instead of all the pckages in tidyverse